# How to connect two models in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new at ASP.NET MVC, and I'm trying to create an app, which stores swimming practices and results.

So I created the application in Visual Studio 2019, and I already succeeded listing, adding, deleting and modifying swimming results. Those data only stored in one model.
But I also would like to store practices, but one practice includes many exercises/drills. So I assumed I need two different model classes for that.

So I created these two classes:

Practice class:

```
public class Practice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Drill> Drills { get; set; }
}
```

Drills class:

```
public class Drill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Multiplier { get; set; }
    public int Distance { get; set; }
    public int? RestTime { get; set; }
    public SwimmingStroke SwimmingStroke { get; set; }
    public String Equipment { get; set; }
    public String Notes { get; set; }
}
```

SwimmingStroke is an enum, which only stores the 4 different swim types.

So I tried this way, and using migrations, Entity Framework generated the database tables for me. It also added a Practice_Id in the Drill table, which I assume is the foreign key.
After that I created the PracticeController. From that, I scaffolded the Index and the Details view. In the Index, I can show the list of practices, but what is more important, when I click on details, I would like to list that practice's drills. Here's where I stuck.

The index method is simple as it could be

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var practices = dbContext.Practices.ToList();
        return View(practices);
    }
```

But in the details method, I cannot figure out what to do.

My goal would be to show a list of drills of the selected practice in the details view.

Comment: Don't use Entity Models as ViewModels! https://ardalis.com/your-api-and-view-models-should-not-reference-domain-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dai mentioned, using entity models directly in your view isn't a great idea. It makes things a bit messy, and your entity model doesn't always accurately represent the information you want your user to see.

I suggest building a class called something along the lines of PracticeModel (by convention, but name it as you wish), which contains a list of DrillModels. Then select the practices and drills into that model and pass that to your view.

```
    public class PracticeModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public List<DrillModel> DrillModels { get; set; }

        public PracticeModel()
        {
            DrillModels = new List<DrillModel>();
        }
    }
```

In your view you can then loop through your PracticeModel's list of DrillModels and display them as necessary. Assuming you'll have multiple Practice Models, create a partial view that displays each practice model. This makes it easy to work with, and you can re-use that partial view all over your website.

```
@model PracticeModel

@if (Model != null)
{
    // PracticeModel Details
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Drills.Count; i++)
    {
        var drill = Model.Drills[i];
        // DrillModel Details
    }
}
else
{
    //Display Appropriate Html
}
```